# How to check what LayoutManager is RecyclerView using?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I wanted to have a simple button that you click to change from `LinearLayoutManager` to `GridLayoutManager` and **vice versa**.

So I wanted to check which Manager is `RecyclerView` using and than change to different one. But I can't seem to find any method that allows me to do that in the documentation.

Is there a method that I can call to check that or will I need two separate buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access RecyclerView's LayoutManager and check what kind of LayoutManager is.

```
 final LayoutManager layoutManager = recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
 if(layoutManager instanceof GridLayoutManager) {

 } else if(layoutManager instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {

 }
 // ...and so on
```

Comment: I'm such a dummy didn't think about instanceof. Thanks!

Comment: This is not working. This always going into LinearLayoutManager.

Comment: You are right @AristoMichael, since GridLayoutManager extends from LinearLayoutManager. In order to work, just need to switch condition order. I have edited my answer and fixed the error.